# How to keep the side lines of columns when changing the background color of a dataframe and appending it to an existing excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have this set of code that takes a dataframe I created and adds it to an existing excel file with values already in it and the background is already yellow. I was able to make it so that when I do add the dataframe, that the dataframe's background color matches the excel file's. Except when I add the dataframe it gets rid of the side column lines like in the picture below.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
     pre_info_df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': '#FFFF00', 'color': 'black'}).to_excel \
     (writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", header=False, startrow=row_to_start_index + 1, startcol=4, index=False)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVNGo.png

Comment: It looks like the issue might be with the header=False parameter that you are passing to the to_excel() method. Setting header=False will remove the column headers from the output, including the leftmost column with the vertical lines.

Comment: @magedo The dataframe has column names and I want to get rid of them before appending the dataframe to the excel file which is why it's false.

Comment: In that case, you can try adding the column names as the first row of your dataframe and then setting header=False to exclude the first row when you write to the Excel file.